# Is it useful using WebView whole layout in native Android app?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-webview

I am currently developing a native android app. My app has a lot of activities. I want to develop `native` android app. But in some case, I want to use a `webview` where the entire layout is just a webview. Not linear or relative or another layout, just a webview. All of the images and other things running in HTML. `All of screen will run in HTML5.`

So, I can partially transfer my app into iphone app or other platforms. This is the benefit of this way to me.

But I don't know. Is this way better? What will the performance be? What is the disadvantages of converting to an HTML5 app?

Can you explain?

Comment: It is alternate way no doubt but application performance depends on your server connection.

Comment: My webview isn't rely on internet. It will work locally.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a [very good presentation](http://martinfowler.com/articles/multiMobile/) about this very topic.

1. Performance: You are adding an additional layer in between, A webkit engine cannot always match native (and sometimes hardware accelerated) rendering performance.
2. Disadvantages: One is that the API use is limited, you can bind a page's JavaScript to Native code, but not all functionality is available.Though you might want to have a look at capabilities of [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) project. Another is that emulating complex widgets via JavaScript will slow down the page.
3. Portability: Indeed is a great advantage, that's why [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) are popular. Though many like Facebook App etc have [switched to native](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/12/13/facebook_native_app_for_android/) App for better performance.

The approach you require actually depends on your requirements. This may be my personal rant but IMHO: a markup can be only twisted so far, it can't out-perform industrial grade GUI programming setups as of yet.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very illustrative.

Comment: @BreedHansen I've updated the first link to a presentation on this topic.

Comment: I'm also switching to Native .... In my case WebView was a false friend, at the beginning everything was promising and cool and whatnot, but as my application became more complex, WebView responsiveness decreased exponentially, specially on stuff regarding user input, that is something critical for the good reputation of an app... Also, a lot of refresh bugs popped in unpredictably and the workarounds were battery eaters (invalidate every onDraw) ... long story short, forget Webview fullscreen for HTML5. Native will be much much cooler. Using small webviews for light tasks is OK in my exp.

Answer (score 3):

**Cons WebView**

- Can't use full performance of device, Since web view form an extra layer.
- Web view can't listen all user event.
- You can't fully share or save data from your web view to app.
- Take more time to load. Other we get all things in a simple API and can be rendered.
- Changing a simple fields in page need to load full page again.
- Online required, can't extend offline features.
- Orientation changes and full screen make difficulties.

**Pros of using Web view**

- One page for both android and IOS.
- I think the main advantage is the ability to make changes without the need for each user to update the app on his device, because all the pages are on your server.
- No wait for app store approval for updation.

**Some Techniques**

- Native elements TOGETHER with WebView. I think it will be much better, as there are a lot of functions that can't be done with WebView only. The combination of the two is much more recommended.
- Rendering from locally, Create an assets directory for HTML files – Android internally maps it to file:///android_asset/ (note singular asset). So you can feed your web view form locally even if you are offline.

Comment: Are you sure about "online required"? You can use the `localStorage` JavaScript object to store data locally for your app. Also, Webview can listen to UI events through jquery, etc.

Comment: Making the app in PWA and using the web view will enable us to store the data offline, its limited but it can render offline. For user events you can simply make an API calls to record or you can use firebase to make a sync. The only disadvantage i see is the performance. Still if its not a gaming app it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think -by using this way- your app quality will be weak and app will be hard to use because the webview object not having a lot of tools that you can make it be compatible with android. e.g you can't share or save data from your webview to app. whatever that reference on your app what need and what dosen't need, by the way i tried to develop an app with html but it was bad.

Comment: I have to disagree, Firstly your webview's content is able to communicate with the application itself easily.. While this is limited, for a good majority of information apps this can be a safer approach.

HTML also does enable a web designer/developer to easily develop an application that would be of a higher quality due to being experienced with HTML/CSS/JS