# Android quick learning resources

Tags: android

I am a web developer having more than 5 years  in web development. I know PHP and JavaScript well . Now I would like to learn Android app development also I am not having sufficient time to read a huge page of documents and tutorials. I have followed tutorials point and slidenerd videos, both are very time consuming . I need direct guide for android development. So can you please suggest links where I can learn android app development quickly.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I just required suggestion where i can start learning android development in short time .

Comment: As I stated, such a question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development with web technologies, look at **Apache Cordova** :

*https://cordova.apache.org*

For game development, look at **Unity Learn** official tutorials :
*http://unity3d.com/learn*

For C# cross platforms development, look at **Xamarin** :

*https://www.xamarin.com*

For native java / xml, look at the official **android training** : *http://developer.android.com*

Comment: Is webview useful ? Does it has any drawbacks ??

Comment: there is a nice presentation about it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024400/is-it-usefull-using-webview-whole-layout-in-native-android-app

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

I was also PHP dev earlier. This link helped me a lot.